# nginx config reverse proxy lose basepath on redirect without slash

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, redirect

i have the following nginx configs to redirect the url path to it's perspective services

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abc.com;
    location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off }
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    

    location /a-ms/ {
       rewrite /a-ms/(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http:host.docker.internal:3000/;
    }
    
    location /b-ms/ {
       rewrite /b-ms/(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http:host.docker.internal:4000/;
    }
    
}
```

the backend microservices using nodejs to host the api and swagger doc

When i got to a url from a browser like `abc.com/a-ms/doc/` it return the swagger normal, but when i go to url without slash for example `abc.com/a-ms/doc` it redirected me to `abc.com/doc` which is not what i wanted(it missing the location path)(. How do i fix this with nginx config settings?

Comment: You can use [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) to correct a 3xx response from your application. Use: `curl -I http://example.com/a-ms/doc` to identify the exact value of the `Location` http response header.

Comment: @RichardSmith i'm getting `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` from the curl -i , whatshould i put proxy_redirect value as?

Comment: Used `-I` (uppercase `I`) to see the value of the `Location:` response header.

Comment: @RichardSmith i checked and the location is /doc/. I updated my nginx config file with proxy_redirect /doc /a-ms/doc and now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following RichardSmith suggestion of using [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) and now my location redirect is correct and included the location path

```
location /a-ms/ {
   rewrite /a-ms/(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http:host.docker.internal:3000/;
   proxy_redirect /doc /a-ms/doc; #add this
}
    
location /b-ms/ {
   rewrite /b-ms/(.*) /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http:host.docker.internal:4000/;
   proxy_redirect /doc /b-ms/doc; #add this
}
```